# MS SQL Need Help storing and processing 2 GB + of JSON data

Tags: sql-server-2016

The following use to work for files under 2 GB.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql='
select
     BulkColumn
into SAMPLE_TABLE
from openrowset(bulk '''+ @FileName + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j
cross apply openjson(BulkColumn)
'

Exec(@sql)
```

Now, I am being asked to process files greater then 2GB, and BulkColumn is a VARHCAR(MAX) column which does not support holding text greater then 2GB.

I would later parse the data out of the SAMPLE_TABLE to other tables.  I figured I would just roll up the process so I could avoid storing the 2GB of data.  The following appears to work, but its incredibly slow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     *
INTO SampleTable_TEMP
FROM (
    SELECT
        Example
        ,Example2
        ,NestedJSON
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Files\ReallyBigFile01of60.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn, '$.ArrayName')
    WITH
    (
         Example     NVARCHAR(20)     '$.value0'
        ,Example2    NVARCHAR(10)     '$.value1'
        ,NestedJSON  NVARCHAR(max) as json 
    ) as Providers
) AS T
```

If anyone has any suggestions, please help.  60 files should not take 90 hours.

Comment: At this point this is a task meant for an ETL tool (e.g. SSIS) or application process, not something you should really be trying to do in pure SQL and expect fast runtimes.

Comment: These are sample queries based on a SP and are running in a custom written ETL software.  I still feel that there should be a faster way, but I know what your saying J.D.

Comment: Do you really need the `DISTINCT` when inserting the data? This will slow down the process which will become a problem when you have a lot of data and not enough memory in your server (I think, but have not done this meself...)

Comment: I'm guessing the `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(...)` is your main bottleneck (aside from the files being 2 GB big). Luuk might be onto something as well regarding Memory pressure in general. I would bet (but this is just a guess) that if you imported the JSON files (as raw JSON) into Tables in the database to materialize them there first, you may find running the `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (...)` query against those Tables faster. Aside from that, the actual execution plan, and running [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) to get the wait types might provide clues on how to improve performance.

Comment: Any chance you could instead use something like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse your JSON files into the desired tabular format? I'm pretty sure it'll be faster.

Comment: Good catch on DISTINCT.  What datatype would you import the raw JSON files into?  This is where the 2GB limit hits me. J.D.  But that was my original process before the recent change to 2GB + files and yes, it was a ton faster.  I have to look up jq mustaccio as I have never used it.

Comment: Is the entire file or a single JSON value a total size of 2 GB?...If it's a single value then that sounds like a design problem.

Comment: The entire file is over 2 GB.